# Run function for every repeated class on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, css-position

I've created the following functionality where an image is fixed on the left while scrolling the content and the quote appears for a few pixels.

It's working all right, the only problem is that I'd like to add this many times on the same page and, as it is, it just works with the first image.

The second one is not fixed while scrolling and the quote maintains hidden...

How can I make run this function for every image?

[This is a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGgYEK)

HTML:

```
<section id="cont_quote" class="maxwidth">
    <article class="cont_q hasImage">
        <p>Content</p>
        <img class="alignleft img_quote" src="/large.jpg" alt="" width="433" height="553" />
       <blockquote>
          <h3>Why this training plan works</h3>
       </blockquote>
       <p>Content</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

JS:

```
// Stick image on scroll 
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        if ($(window).width() >= 769) {
          var $element = $('#cont_quote');
          var $follow = $element.find('.img_quote');
          var followHeight = $element.find('.img_quote').outerHeight();
          var height = $element.outerHeight() - 300;
          var window_height = $(window).height();

          $(window).scroll(function () {
            var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var top = $element.offset().top;

            // Check if element is above or totally below viewport
            if (top + height - followHeight < pos || top > pos + window_height) {
              return;
            }

            var offset = parseInt($(window).scrollTop() - top);

            if (offset > 0) {
            $follow.css('transform', 'translateY('+ offset +'px)');
            }

          })
        }
    });


    // Quote show on viewport
    function inViewport( element, viewport = { top: 0, bottom: innerHeight } ){

      // Get the elements position relative to the viewport

      var bb = element.getBoundingClientRect();

      // Check if the element is outside the viewport
      // Then invert the returned value because you want to know the opposite

      return !(bb.top > viewport.bottom || bb.bottom < viewport.top);

    }

    var myViewport = { top: innerHeight * .5, bottom: innerHeight * .6 };
    var myElement = document.querySelector( '#cont_quote blockquote' );

    // Listen for the scroll event

    document.addEventListener( 'scroll', event => {


    // Check the viewport status
    if( $(window).width() >= 600 ){

      if( inViewport( myElement, myViewport ) && $('.cont_q').hasClass('hasImage') ) {

        if( $(window).width() >= 769 ){
          myElement.style.opacity = 1;
          myElement.style.left = '-25%';

        } else {
          myElement.style.opacity = 1;
          myElement.style.left = '-5%';
        }

       } else if( inViewport( myElement, myViewport )) {

        if( $(window).width() >= 769 ){
          myElement.style.opacity = 1;
          myElement.style.left = '-15%';

        } else {
          myElement.style.opacity = 1;
          myElement.style.left = '13%';
        }

      } else {

        myElement.style.opacity = 0;
        myElement.style.left = '-40%';
      }   

    } else {

        myElement.style.opacity = 1;
        myElement.style.left = '5%';
    } 

    });
```

Comment: But you only have one image in your example?

Comment: @cullimorer you're right. I've added the second section on codepen